# Unable to resolve some modules:Meteor 1.3 with ECMAScript

Tags: meteor, youtube, npm, ecmascript-6

I am adding video upload to youtube so I am using npm module Youtube-video-api.And then adding ECMAScript import youtube-video-api on client side.

So added Meteor package: meteor add ecmascript

I get the error:

```js
Unable to resolve some modules:

  "eventEmitter" in /home/ananth/GREENROOM/greenroom/app/client/lib/plugins/core.min.js (web.browser)
  "eventie" in /home/ananth/GREENROOM/greenroom/app/client/lib/plugins/core.min.js (web.browser)
  "fs" in /home/ananth/GREENROOM/greenroom/app/node_modules/nightmare-google-oauth2/node_modules/request/lib/har.js (web.browser)
  "path" in /home/ananth/GREENROOM/greenroom/app/node_modules/nightmare/lib/nightmare.js (web.browser)
  "url" in /home/ananth/GREENROOM/greenroom/app/node_modules/nightmare-google-oauth2/index.js (web.browser)
  "util" in /home/ananth/GREENROOM/greenroom/app/node_modules/nightmare-google-oauth2/node_modules/request/request.js (web.browser)
  "querystring" in /home/ananth/GREENROOM/greenroom/app/node_modules/nightmare-google-oauth2/node_modules/request/lib/har.js (web.browser)
  "net" in /home/ananth/GREENROOM/greenroom/app/node_modules/forever-agent/index.js (web.browser)
  "punycode" in /home/ananth/GREENROOM/greenroom/app/node_modules/tough-cookie/lib/cookie.js (web.browser)
  "crypto" in /home/ananth/GREENROOM/greenroom/app/node_modules/nightmare-google-oauth2/node_modules/request/lib/oauth.js (web.browser)
  "http" in /home/ananth/GREENROOM/greenroom/app/node_modules/nightmare-google-oauth2/node_modules/request/request.js (web.browser)
  "https" in /home/ananth/GREENROOM/greenroom/app/node_modules/nightmare-google-oauth2/node_modules/request/request.js (web.browser)
  "stream" in /home/ananth/GREENROOM/greenroom/app/node_modules/nightmare-google-oauth2/node_modules/request/request.js (web.browser)
  "zlib" in /home/ananth/GREENROOM/greenroom/app/node_modules/nightmare-google-oauth2/node_modules/request/request.js (web.browser)
  "buffer" in /home/ananth/GREENROOM/greenroom/app/node_modules/bl/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js (web.browser)
  "events" in /home/ananth/GREENROOM/greenroom/app/node_modules/nightmare/lib/ipc.js (web.browser)
  "dgram" in /home/ananth/GREENROOM/greenroom/app/node_modules/request/node_modules/sntp/lib/index.js (web.browser)
  "dns" in /home/ananth/GREENROOM/greenroom/app/node_modules/request/node_modules/sntp/lib/index.js (web.browser)
  "assert" in /home/ananth/GREENROOM/greenroom/app/node_modules/verror/lib/verror.js (web.browser)
  "tls" in /home/ananth/GREENROOM/greenroom/app/node_modules/forever-agent/index.js (web.browser)
  "child_process" in /home/ananth/GREENROOM/greenroom/app/node_modules/nightmare/lib/nightmare.js (web.browser)

Consider running: meteor npm install --save eventEmitter eventie meteor-node-stubs
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Well, have you considered running: `meteor npm install --save eventEmitter eventie meteor-node-stubs` ?

Comment: Thanks MasterAM, its working but npm module eventEmitter is not working because no npm module in "eventEmitter". I tried npm modules "events", "emitter", "eventemitter" .

Comment: I tried event-emitter but not working this error occur only i added ecmascript package suppose i removed this package working but added not working.